# No matching distribution found for torch==1.3.0 while installing PTAN

Tags: python, pip, reinforcement-learning

I tried to install PTAN liblary using pip

```
python -m pip install PTAN==0.6
```

But it shows error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.3.0 (from ptan)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.3.0
```

I can install it by running:

```
python -m pip install PTAN
```

But then I get old version of this.

**How to install current version of PTAN without errors?**

I'm using Linux ubuntu and Python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ptan 0.6` is broken at the time being. The issue is that the dependencies are requiring exact versions of the same package (`torch` in this case) which pip cannot handle as it uninstalls the previous version.

I tried finding what other package was requiring a version of `torch` that's not version `1.3.0` but I couldn't find it, maybe somebody else could find it, not that it matters too much for us though.

Your best bet is to install the older [version](https://pypi.org/project/ptan/#history) of `ptan` which is `0.4` released July 1:st 2020.

`pip install ptan==0.4`

Comment: end of 2021 and still no other solutions ? my only option to use ptan as local package

Comment: is this still the case in 2022?

Comment: Yeah it hasn't been updated for [17 months](https://github.com/Shmuma/ptan). I tried the latest ptan (0.7) but pip cannot resolve its 1.7 torch requirement, probably since there have been 10 newer releases for torch. Like Ramzy said you can clone the repo and change it to use the latest torch in `setup.py` and then do `pip install .`. All tests passed for me but it spat out a lot of deprecation warnings, seems fine for a temporary solution